# Monitor size that Ubuntu autodetects

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi, lg

How does Ubuntu determine the size of the display in inches?

I have the 27'inch LG display as a main monitor that is connected to my dell laptop via HDMI. And as shown on the screen attached Ubuntu detects it as 23' inch. Is it ok? If not I just wander how can I set up it properly for 27 inch display?

[Display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bNK7.png)

Comment: It probably has something to do with a generic driver. It's completely irrelevant/inconsequential anyway since the only thing that matters is aspect ratio and screen resolution